# Return CSRF token in JSON response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, csrf

I'm building an application that will (hopefully) handle session creation and destroying over JSON. Currently, the best way I have found of doing this is to have Rails return the `form_authentication_token` as part of a successful JSON response to a login, i.e. (in my Api::SessionsController):

```
def create
  @user = User.find_for_authentication(email: params[:email])

  if @user && @user.valid_password?(params[:password])
    sign_in(@user)
    render json: { success: true, token: form_authenticity_token }
  else
    render json: { success: false, errors: ['Invalid email or password'] }, status: 401
  end
end
```

However, my knowledge of CSRF-related security isn't solid enough to know if this is a bad thing to do. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I think this should be a safe thing to do. Same Origin policies should protect you from a malicious site being able to perform a CSRF login of one of your users and subsequently stealing the token from the response. The browser will not submit a JSON request to a host on a different domain.

Something like JSON hijacking (http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/24/json-hijacking.aspx) is theoretically possible (though it has been patched in all browsers that I know of), but that threat should be mitigated as well assuming the following:

- You only return the token in the create action
- This action is only accessible via a post request